# what's wrong with this code? I have just started learning Python

Tags: python

```
print "Welcome to the English to Pig Latin translator!"
original = raw_input("Enter a word.")
if len(original) is > 0:
    print original
else:
    print "empty"
```

Comment: Please edit this post to include what is going wrong.  If there is an error message, please copy and paste that error message.

Comment: In general, we expect you to tell us what's wrong with it as far as you can. Also note that the error message you are getting is correct, and likely tells you exactly what is wrong.

Comment: See in the top right corner there - a little box marked `Search`. Put 'Python Pig Latin' in there and press Enter. It'll give you a list of all the other people who've asked the same question, and all the answers they got. Try it - it could save you hours.

Comment: @MikeW not really - the problem is different

Comment: @Volatility Maybe, but with so many questions about this exact piece of code it's bound to be close to one of them!

Answer (score 7):

well, your error is in this line:

```
if len(original) is > 0:
```

`is` checks whether the left side and the right side point to the same object in memory. But you made [`is`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) followed by another comparator operator [`>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm), which compares left value with right value.

So the python interpreter does not get what you want :

```
value operator operator value
```

has no sense for it (with a few exceptions like the `not in`)

The correct way to write that is

```
if len(original) > 0:
```

that uses the `>` operator to compare left and right value.

Furthermore, @Volatility makes a point in his comment, if you want to check whether a string is empty, python has a really elegant syntax to check it:

```
if original:
```

as an empty string will valuate as `False` in a boolean context.

Comment: To be fair, `not in` and `is not` *are* single operators despite containing multiple words.

Comment: The best way to write it though would be `if original:`, using the fact that empty strings evaluate to `False` in a boolean context.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams indeed, though I had to make that precision for my point to be clear :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(original) is > 0:
```

should be

```
if len(original) > 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if len(original) is > 0:
```

Python is not exactly like English :)

```
if len(original) > 0:
```